# easy calculus result about images of set under a function

Tags: calculus, functions

> #### PROBLEM:
>
> Let $f: X \to Y $ be a function and $\{ A_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in \Gamma}$ be a collection of  subsets of $X$, then it
>   occurs that $$ f( \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} A_{\alpha} ) \subseteq
>  \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} f(A_{\alpha})$$

#### Attempted solution:

Let $y \in f( \bigcap_{\alpha \in \Gamma} A_{\alpha} ) $. So, there exists $x \in \bigcap A_{\alpha} $ such that $y = f(x)$. Hence, $x \in A_{\alpha}$ for all the $\alpha's$ such that $y = f(x)$. In particular, $y \in f( A_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha$. Hence, $y \in \bigcap f(A_{\alpha} )$

Is this a correct solution. Also, why don't we have equality? It seems that this argument also works in the opposite direction and hence giving equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is right. To see that the opposite is false, take a non-injective function $f$. Then there exist $x \neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)=r$. Then you have
$$ \emptyset = f(\{x\} \cap \{y\}) \subsetneq \{f(x)\} \cap \{f(y)\} = \{r\} $$

In fact, you can prove that if the equality holds, then $f$ must be injective, and conversely. It is a characterization if injectivity.

---

If you start the other way around, take $y \in \cap f(A_\alpha)$. This means that for each $\alpha$ there exists $x_\alpha \in A_\alpha$ such that $f(x_\alpha)=y$. Now you would like to prove that you can take all $x_\alpha$ equal to some $x$ in the intersection of all $A_\alpha$. This is not always possible. It is here that we need injectivity. If $f$ is injective then all $x_\alpha$ must be equal. If $f$ is not injective, then take the initial counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. My question is though where in my proof ( if we go the reverse direction) we have a flaw so that we cant have $ \bigcap f( A_{\alpha} ) \subset f ( \bigcap A_{\alpha}) $